# Launch Jetty 9 Programmatically

Tags: java, spring, jetty

Does someone know how to launch Jetty9 with a simple main in Java class???
For example, I've seen programs like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Server server = new Server(8080);
        WebAppContext webAppContext = new WebAppContext("./src/main/webapp", "/recruiting");
        webAppContext.setLogUrlOnStart(true);
        webAppContext.setInitParameter(ContextLoader.CONTEXT_CLASS_PARAM, RecruitingAppContext.class.getName());
        webAppContext.addServlet(DispatcherServlet.class, "/");
        webAppContext.setWelcomeFiles(new String[]{"index.jsp"});
        webAppContext.addEventListener(new RequestContextListener());
        webAppContext.configure();

        server.setHandler(webAppContext);
        server.start();
        System.out.println("Server started");
        server.join();
    }
```

But I'm not yet able to run Jetty9 successfully. Anyway, I'm trying to do this with spring.
Do someone let me see some examples in order to do this???
Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: What exactly does not work?

Comment: In this program example, there is a message in error which says that JSP is not configured... At the moment under webapp folder I have the index.jsp and WEB-INF folder that's empty

Comment: Looks like you are missing a required jar, then

Comment: My intention is does not use any maven plug-in nor jetty standalone

Comment: I saw in some other examples that is used SelectChannelConnector class, but in jetty9 distribution this class does not exist

Comment: Note that sample code for the older versions of Jetty hosted at Codehaus do not unconditionally work for the latest hosted at Eclipse.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just documented one of our examples here a couple weeks back.  We'll be documenting more of our examples and adding some as we get requests and as folks submit their own...

anyway, this ought to get you going :)

http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/embedded-examples.html#embedded-one-webapp